# CPU Usage Unusually High when running simple tensorflow script using Docker image tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

Tags: docker, tensorflow2.0

I am running tensorflow on a server on linux using a docker image. When running an extremely simple tensorflow script shown below, the code hangs indefinitely and CPU usage jumps to 100%. Docker image is tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(gpus)

a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])

print('DONE')
```

It correctly identifies that there are 2 available GPUs but when trying to assign a constant the program hangs indefinitely until killed. Output of the script and CPU usage is shown below. Any help would be much appreciated.

[CPU Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYdph.png)

[Output when running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RuJy.png)